# Excel files not showing on Heroku web app

Tags: python, django, excel, heroku, openpyxl

I have a django backed website on Heroku and every time I try to view/download the upload excel files after uploading them on the Heroku website I get this error:

```
Not Found: The requested URL /excel_files/<file> was not found on this server.
```

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from .forms import UploadForm
from django.conf import settings
import os

import openpyxl, re

def index(request):
    """The home page which generates the donor list html page"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = UploadForm()
    else:
        form = UploadForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            file = request.FILES['fileobj'].name
            file_corrected = file.replace(" ", "_")
            path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_corrected)
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
            sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
            text_file = open('upload/templates/upload/donor_list.html', 'w')

            html1 = "{% extends 'upload/base.html' %}" + "\n" + "{% block header %}" + "\n" + "  <h1>Donor List</h1>" + "\n" + "{% endblock header %}" + "\n" + "{% block content %}" + "\n"
            html2 = "{% endblock content %}"
            text_file.write(html1)

            for rowNum in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
                firstName = str(sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value)
                if firstName == "None":
                    firstName = "\n"
                lastName = str(sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=2).value)
                addNum = re.compile(r'\d(\d)*')
                addressNumber1 = addNum.search(str(sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value))
                if addressNumber1 is None:
                    addressNumber = ""
                if addressNumber1 is not None:
                    addressNumber = addressNumber1.group(0)
                donate = str(sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=4).value)
                donate = "$" + donate
                if donate == "$None":
                    donate = ""
                date = str(sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=7).value)
                year = date[2:4]
                if year == "ne":
                    year = ""
                if firstName == "\n" and lastName != "None":
                    firstName = str(sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=2).value)
                    lastName = str(sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value)
                    addressNumber1 = addNum.search(str(sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=4).value))
                    addressNumber = addressNumber1.group(0)
                    donate = str(sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=5).value)
                    donate = "$" + donate
                    date = str(sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=8).value)
                    year = date[2:4]
                if firstName is "_" or lastName is "Anonymous":
                    text_file.write("""  <p>{} (Mr./Ms.) {} {} {}.</p>""".format(addressNumber, lastName, donate, year) + '\n')

                else:
                    text_file.write("""  <p>{} {} {} {}.</p>""".format(addressNumber, firstName, donate, year) + '\n')

            text_file.write(html2)
            text_file.close()
            return donor_list(request)
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'upload/index.html', context)

def instructions(request):
    """The how-to for file uploading"""
    return render(request, 'upload/instructions.html')

def donor_list(request):
    """Webpage with the donor list after upload"""
    return render(request, 'upload/donor_list.html')
```

and here is my settings.py as it relates to the Heroku website:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# Heroku settings
cwd = os.getcwd()
if cwd == '/app' or cwd[:4] == '/tmp':
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
    }

    # Honor the "X-Forwarded_Proto' header for request.is.secure().
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

    # Allow only Heroku to host the project
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['WEBSITE_URL_HERE']
    DEBUG = False


    # Static asset configuration
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )

    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'excel_files')
    MEDIA_URL = '/excel_files/'
```

Notice that my views.py after upload displays the excel file as text using openpyxl module, but i find it odd that I can't seem to access these excel files on my Heroku admin page; they are listed but I can't download them as I described above. Beginner friendly answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must not upload files to the filesystem on Heroku. As the documentation explains, the filesystem is ephemeral and is not shared between dynos. Anything uploaded will only be seen by the dyno that created it, and will be completely lost when that dunno restarts.

You must use a permanent store, for example S3.